# SqlAlchemy TypeDecorator, column_expression and aggregate functions

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I found my problem solution on SqlAlchemy docs

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BYTEA

class PGPString(BYTEA):
    def __init__(self, passphrase, length=None):
        super(PGPString, self).__init__(length)
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        # convert the bind's type from PGPString to
        # String, so that it's passed to psycopg2 as is without
        # a dbapi.Binary wrapper
        bindvalue = type_coerce(bindvalue, String)
        return func.pgp_sym_encrypt(bindvalue, self.passphrase)

    def column_expression(self, col):
        return func.pgp_sym_decrypt(col, self.passphrase)
```

It produces query as expected:

```
 SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(employees.salary, $1) AS salary_crypt FROM employees
```

But, when I try to wrap PGPString column with any aggregate expression

```
 session.query(func.sum(Employee.salary))
```

below query is produced by the expression above:

```
 SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(sum(salary_rate_employee_link.salary_crypt), $1) AS sum_1
```

and what I expected

```
SELECT sum(pgp_sym_decrypt(salary_rate_employee_link.salary_crypt, $1)) AS sum_1
```

As you can see the order of db functions is not one I expected. So, I would like to find a simple way to make it properly work

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only solution, I came up by now is kind of a workaround

```
class PGPString(BYTEA):
    def __init__(self, passphrase, length=None):
        super(PGPString, self).__init__(length)
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        # convert the bind's type from PGPString to
        # String, so that it's passed to psycopg2 as is without
        # a dbapi.Binary wrapper
        bindvalue = type_coerce(bindvalue, String)
        return func.pgp_sym_encrypt(bindvalue, self.passphrase)

    def column_expression(self, col):
        clauses = getattr(col, 'clauses', [col])
        columns = [
            db.func.pgp_sym_decrypt(clause, self.passphrase)
            for clause in clauses
        ]

        if isinstance(col, FunctionElement):
            if col.base_columns:
                base_column, *base_columns = col.base_columns
                columns = type(base_column)(*columns)
                for base_column in base_columns:
                    columns = type(base_column)(columns)
        else:
            columns = columns[0]

        return columns
```